# Bad canvas context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently working on a canvas animation, it works pretty well.

You can check out my code below:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('bubble'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.save();

var wW = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
    wH = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var particles = [];
var particleIndex = 0;
var dx = dy = distance = 0;

function Particle(){
  this.x = Math.random() * wW;
  this.y = Math.random() * wH;
  this.rad = 20;
  this.color = "blue";
  this.vX =  Math.random() * (1.01 - (-1)) + (-1);
  this.vY =  Math.random() * (1.01 - (-1)) + (-1);
  particles[particleIndex] = this;
  particleIndex++;
}
    
Particle.prototype.draw = function(){
  this.x += this.vX;
  this.y += this.vY;
  
  this.collision();
  
  //outer
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  //center
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad/10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.fill();
}

Particle.prototype.collision = function(){
 if(this.x + this.rad >= wW || this.x - this.rad <= 0){
   this.vX *= -1;
 }
  
 if(this.y + this.rad >= wH || this.y - this.rad <= 0){
   this.vY *= -1;
 }
 
}

function line(){
  for(var i=0; i < particles.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j < particles.length; j++){
      dx = particles[i].x - particles[j].x;
      dy = particles[i].y - particles[j].y;
      distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

      if(distance <= 60){        
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(particles[i].x, particles[i].y);
         ctx.lineTo(particles[j].x, particles[j].y);
         ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(0,0,0,"+ 6/distance +")";
         ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
  }
}
  
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
  new Particle();
}

function anim(){
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,wW,wH);
  
  line();
  
  for(var i=0; i < particles.length; i++){
    particles[i].draw();
  }
}

anim();
```

```css
html, body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bubble"></canvas>
```

I have a function line() which calculates the space between each circle and draws line between them.
In this function, i put this :

```
 ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(0,0,0,"+ 6/distance +")";
```

I want to change the line opacity as a function of distance. However, it changes the circle opacity and not the line. I don't understand why, I tried to restore the context but it did not work..

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store it to a variable before starting the line drawing and revert it afterwards

```
function line() {
  var originalStrokeStyle = ctx.strokeStyle;
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
      dx = particles[i].x - particles[j].x;
      dy = particles[i].y - particles[j].y;
      distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        if (distance <= 60) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(particles[i].x, particles[i].y);
          ctx.lineTo(particles[j].x, particles[j].y);
          ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0," + 6 / distance + ")";
          ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = originalStrokeStyle;
}
```

Updated demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/aBZpXJ

Comment: :laughs: Precisely the change I toyed with while editing the code into the post. Although, I chose the name `origStrokeStyle`